# How to know if resource file is loaded by the page in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I  to know if resource file is loaded by a page using Javascript?

For example some .css, js or other sort of sort of file?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you're adding the files dynamically. I'll explain for JavaScript files.

Either use this piece of code to load an external file:

```
var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');

scriptElem.onload = function() {alert('Script loaded.');}

scriptElem.src = 'test.js';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElem);
```

Or if you're adding them through HTML, you can make the script file reflect the fact it's been loaded with a variable. E.g. in `test.js`:

```
// ...rest of file...

window.testLoaded = true;
```

You can then check for `window.testLoaded === true` anywhere on the page.

For CSS files you can also use the first technique, but of course not the second. It might be possible to define a stub definition for a class `.test`, then create an element with that class and check whether it has a certain style that you set in the CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery.ready event which means that all the page has been setup and then you start executing your JavaScript logic

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //your code
});
```

If you have the need to load stuff asynchronously then you should use your JavaScript code to load it like the example of loading a script:

```
$.getScript("http://.../some.js", function(){
  //script loaded and hooked on the page; your custom logic here
});
```

For anything more complex I'd suggest some dependency management system like [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/).